# FPDF, FPDI - how can I combine separate files each with unique text using PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm stuck with using fpdf and fpdi.

I'm using this code to create 1 pdf file from 5 or more files (!important) and would like to input unique text on each page. the code in its current form puts page01test on every page rather than page02test on page 2 etc.

Each Document imported consists of one page.

I got the base of this code from: http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/

```
require('fpdf.php');
require('fpdi.php');
class ConcatPdf extends FPDI
{
public $files = array();

public function setFiles($files)
{
    $this->files = $files;
}

public function concat()
{
    foreach($this->files AS $file) {
        $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
            $this->AddFont('NotoSans', '', 'notosans.php');
            $this->SetFont('NotoSans', '', 18);
            $this->SetTextColor(63,76,89);

            if ($pageNo == 1) {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page01test');
            }
            if ($pageNo == 2) {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page02test');
            }
            if ($pageNo == 3) {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page03test');
            }
            if ($pageNo == 4) {
                $this->Write(5, 'page04test');
            }
            if ($pageNo == 5) {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page05test');
            }
        }           
    }
 }
}


$pdf = new ConcatPdf();
$pdf->setFiles(array("Proposal1.pdf", "Proposal2.pdf","Proposal3.pdf", "Proposal4.pdf","Proposal5.pdf"));
$pdf->concat();
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Do you have a question or issue?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that i hadn't made it very clear. it's not working in it's current form, i wondered how I could alter the code in order to allow the text on each page to be unique, so page01test on page 1, page02test on page 2 etc.

Comment: The code looks "ok"... Did you made sure that it is not a cache problem? Try to force the browser to load a fresh version by adding a random get-parameter to the URL.

Comment: It's not working when adding in a get-parameter either. I'm stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around with this and have found the answer myself through trial and error,

```
require('customervalues.php');
require('fpdf.php');
require('fpdi.php');

class ConcatPdf extends FPDI
{
public $files = array();

public function setFiles($files)
{
    $this->files = $files;
}

public function concat()
{
    foreach ($this->files AS $file) {
        $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
            $this->AddFont('NotoSans', '', 'notosans.php');
            $this->SetFont('NotoSans', '', 18);
            $this->SetTextColor(63,76,89);
            if ($file == 'Proposal1.pdf') {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page01test');
            }
            if ($file == 'Proposal2.pdf') {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page02test');
            }
            if ($file == 'Proposalxl.pdf') {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page03test');
            }
            if ($file == 'Proposal4.pdf') {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page04test');
                $this->SetXY(55, 150);
                $this->Write(5, 'page04test2');
            }
            if ($file == 'Proposal5.pdf') {
                $this->SetXY(55, 94);
                $this->Write(5, 'page05test');
            }

        }           
    }
}
}

$pdf = new ConcatPdf();
$pdf->setFiles(array("Proposal1.pdf", "Proposal2.pdf","Proposalxl.pdf", "Proposal4.pdf","Proposal5.pdf"));
$pdf->concat();
$pdf->Output();
```

This allows me to write unique text on each page and export it as a final document. there might be cheaper ways to do it however it works for my needs.

Comment: Isn't "unique text on each page" much different to "unique text for each document"? Your result doesn't fit to your initial question.

Comment: The initial question states that each file will have unique text, each file is only one page, I'm sorry I didn't make this clear but I couldn't find any other way of doing it as the code that you said looked ok failed to work.